# Symbolic link Apple Loops

Tags: terminal, sudo, symlink

I am trying to create a symbolic link for my Apple Loops since I want to save it in my external HDD 
I copied my Apple Loops folder into my HDD and changed the root folders name to "s".

Then I input the below command to terminal

```
    sudo ln -s /Volumes/exHDD/Library/Audio/Apple\ Loops
```

Then the return was

```
ln: illegal option -- ?
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file
```

What did I do wrong? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE

So I just want to move my Apple Loops folder to my external HDD so that I don't need to store the apple loops in my computer.  Is my method wrong?

Comment: The command in your question doesn't explain the error message. The command shown would create a symlink named `Apple Loops` in the current folder, whether or not the target path exists. Also, please clarify - in your question - what you mean by "changed the root folder's name to 's'".

Comment: Thank you. I changed the name to s for the Apple Loops folder in the Audio folder in the Library. Is my command wrong>

Comment: I don't fully understand, but `ln -s /path/to/foo` creates a symlink named `foo` in the current directory whose target is `/path/to/foo` - I have no explanation for the error message you're getting. Also, please add clarifications _directly to you question_ - don't post them in _comments_.

Comment: ok um... I clarified it more

Comment: Again: If I execute your command exactly as posted, it does what I described (even though I don't have a `/Volumes/exHDD/Library/Audio/Apple Loops` folder), so your question doesn't contain enough information for others to diagnose your problem (at least as far as I can tell) - `-s` is a legal option; it creates a symlink, as is your intent; the error message doesn't make sense with the information given.

Comment: ok.  but terminal gives this error message. what should I do to create a symbolic link so that I can use my apple loops in my HDD

Comment: Narrow down the problem yourself until you can provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as you can get to one.